# how can I read this XML Document?

Tags: xml, xmldocument, xmlreader

I'm still new on programming and I want to read an XML Document. It looks something like this sample-code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Etapa nombre="EnemigosTest" paredH="30" paredV="40">
  <Personaje vida="90" posX="24" posY="10">Cuberin</Personaje>
  <Items>
    <Item tipo="vida" maxApariciones="0" duracion="none" />
    <Item tipo="velocidad" maxApariciones="0" duracion="none" />
  </Items>
  <Plataformas>
    <Plataforma tipo="normal" posX="0" posY="36" ancho="1" duracion="none" />
    <Plataforma tipo="normal" posX="1" posY="36" ancho="1" duracion="none" />
  </Plataformas>
</Etapa>
```

Also, is there a method to know how many nodes/atributtes/elements are in the document?

Comment: Also, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts

Comment: What platform/programming language do you want to use?

Answer (score 1):

```
    XDocument xDocument = XDocument.Load(string URI);
    Debug.WriteLine(xDocument.Elements().Count().ToString()); 

    foreach (XElement xl in xDocument.Elements())
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(xl.Count().ToString());
        foreach (XAttribute xa in xl.Attributes())
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(xa.ToString());
        }
    }
```